.net MAUI CollectionView fully refreshes when adding an item
This is kind of a weird one.
I have a properly functioning CollectionView in a page of a .net MAUI Windows application.
When I say "properly functioning" I mean: the bound data (coming in from a view model) is correctly populated and the collection view properly displays it.
If I add an element to the underlying model, it properly updates EXCEPT that every time the collection of items changes, the whole CollectionView refreshes, which manifests in the CollectionView area clearing out and the items fading in (like a fade-in animation).
Is this the expected behaviour? Can it be avoided?
I am pretty sure the collection of items is not being destroyed or re-created when I add the items (which would explain the behaviour). Any suggestion is more than welcome, and appreciated in advance.
Just for completeness: the issue happens whenever a new item is added to this ItemsToList observable collection, independently of whether the item is added as part of the Command execution (as shown here) or by any other means.
Relevant code in the view file (abridged for readability, but this is the essence of it):
    <CollectionView
        x:Name="messageCollectionView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsToList}"
        ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"                                
        SelectionMode="None">

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ItemsToList">
                <Grid
                    Padding="5">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" />
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.Template>

    </CollectionView>

    <Button
        Text="Add Item"
        Command="{Binding AddITem}" />


Relevant Model Code:

public class ItemToList
{
    public string? ItemName {  get; set; }
    public string? ItemDescription { get; set; }
    
}


Relevant View Model Code (abridged for readability, but this is the essence of it):

public ObservableCollection<ItemToList> ItemsToList { get; } = [];

public ItemsToList()
{
    this.ItemsToList = new ObservableCollection<ItemToList>();
}

[RelayCommand]
async Task AddItemToList() 
{
    var newItem = new ItemToList
    {
        ItemName = "Test 123",
        ItemDescription = "The new item description here"
    }

    try
    {
        ItemsToList.Add(newItem);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}


please post the relevant code

Ok, so... for whatever it's worth:
I don't consider this a solution to the problem, but it does offer me an immediate sort of workaround to what is a very annoying visual "glitch".
I implemented a custom handler for the CollectionView as follows:
public partial class CustomCollectionViewHandler : CollectionViewHandler
{

    protected override ListViewBase CreatePlatformView()
    {
        var repeater = base.CreatePlatformView();
        DisableAnimations(repeater);
        return repeater;
    }

    private void DisableAnimations(ListViewBase repeater) 
    { 
        repeater.ItemContainerTransitions = null;
    }

}

I created the method DisableAnimations so that it is possible to selectively disable only SOME of those - although in my case, I just had to disable them all to not have the glitch.
For completeness: you should be able to selectively disable only SOME animations (for example, the opacity animation, in the example that follows), but this didn't really work for me (this code would go in the same DisableAnimations method) and I have no idea why:
var transitionCollection = new TransitionCollection();
var addDeleteThemeTransition = new AddDeleteThemeTransition();
var repositionThemeTransition = new RepositionThemeTransition();
transitionCollection.Add(addDeleteThemeTransition);
transitionCollection.Add(repositionThemeTransition);
repeater.ItemContainerTransitions = transitionCollection;

Anyway, the custom handler as coded above will make the visual glitch unnoticeable - the "refresh" is still happening, you just don't "see it", so I am still looking for an answer to the issue itself.
I've dug around A LOT, and this seems possibly related to this issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17369
For now, I'll keep digging, and maybe someone comes by this question and have some suggestions or actual answers?
